# How to read output from subprocess Popen correctly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I'm trying to redirect stderr to stdout and read the output of a command. It looks like the code works, but when it reaches the end of the output, it throws an exception

Code:

```
with Popen(["bash", "-c", "for ((i=0;i<10;i++)); do echo $i; sleep .5; done"],
           stderr=subprocess.STDOUT) as proc:
    out, err = proc.communicate()
    for line in out:
        if line:
            print(line)
```

Output:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-3c150d6a4092> in <module>()
      2            stderr=subprocess.STDOUT) as proc:
      3         out, err = proc.communicate()
----> 4         for line in out:
      5                 if line:
      6                         print(line)

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Comment: `stderr=subprocess.PIPE`

Answer (score 1):

Oh, looks like I need to set stdout=PIPE, and I don't need `communicate()`

```
with Popen(["bash", "-c", "for ((i=0;i<10;i++)); do echo $i; sleep .5; done"],
           stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT) as proc:
    for line in proc.stdout:
        print(line.decode().rstrip())
```

With J.F. Sebastian's universal_newlines tip:

```
with Popen(["bash", "-c", "for ((i=0;i<10;i++)); do echo $i; sleep .5; done"],
           stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
           stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, 
           universal_newlines=True) as proc:
    for line in proc.stdout:
        print(line, end='')
```

Comment: you can drop `if line` condition; `line` is never empty here (a newline is not stripped). You could use `universal_newlines=True` to enable text mode (to avoid calling `line.decode()` manually). You could use just `print(line, end='')` in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I see, you can achive what you want using another approach, but I would like to explain what was happining with your first version.

The thing is you don't have any `PIPE` for output in `proc`, so the output don't "travel" through your script, it goes directly to the screen, thats the reason you see the output:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

and then in the line:

```
out, err = proc.communicate() # out is None, since you don't 
                              # pass the argument "stdout=subprocess.PIPE"
                              # when creating proc.
```

and later when you try to iterate over `out`:

```
for line in out:  # TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
     ...          # We are talking about out variable here, which is None.
     print(line)  # This line never get hit.
```

### Solution.

Here you have a little example redirecting `stdout` to `stderr` and using `communicate`:

```
import subprocess
import sys

proc = subprocess.Popen(['ls'], stderr=sys.stdout, shell=True) # Not the use of sys.stdout
out, err = proc.communicate()
print(err.decode("utf-8"))
```

Answer (score 0):

> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

You should add `stdout=PIPE` otherwise `.communicate()` *always* returns `None` for `out`.

btw, If your code uses `stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT` then `err` is *always* `None` and `out` contains merged stdout/stderr as a single bytestring i.e., `for byte in out` yields one byte at a time, **not** line.

You could get stdout/stderr separately if you set `stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE` and call `.communicate()`.