# Subprocess PIPE stdout to two different processes

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I am trying to redirect a `subprocess` `stdout` to two different processes.
Doing it to one works fine, but not quite working with two different processes

Code:

```
def terminate_processes(*args):
    try:
        for i in reversed(args):
            try:
                i.terminate()
            except:
                pass
    except:
        pass

def main(x='192.168.0.2'):


    # system('sudo nmap -O '+x+'|grep "Running: " > os_detect.txt')
    # system('cat os_detect.txt|cut -d " " -f2 > os.txt')
    # system('cat os_detect.txt|cut -d " " -f3 > os_version.txt')
    
    p1 = subprocess.Popen(['sudo', 'nmap', '-O', str(x)], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    
    p2 = subprocess.Popen(['grep', 'Running: '],  stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    
    p3 = subprocess.Popen(['cut', '-d', ' ', '-f2'],  stdin=p2.stdout,
                                                    stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
                                                    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
                                                    universal_newlines=True)
    
    p4 = subprocess.Popen(['cut', '-d', ' ', '-f3'],  stdin=p2.stdout,
                                                    stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
                                                    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
                                                    universal_newlines=True)

    while p3.poll() is None:
        for line in p3.stdout.readlines():
            if line.strip():
                print(line.strip())

    while p4.poll() is None:
        for line in p4.stdout.readlines():
            if line.strip():
                print(line.strip())

    terminate_processes(p1,p2,p3,p4)
```

As i said should work in theory cause works when only using `p3` and not `p4`,
but not working in this case maybe because the `stdout` is locked.

Any guidance would be really appreciated.

And i am reversing the `args` array inside terminate function cause killing the child process before killing the parent one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way that `.read()` generally works, in most cases that I'm aware of, in order to use it a second time, you'd have to use `.seek()` to rewind the read head back to where it was before.

see:

- [Why can't I call read() twice on an open file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3906137/why-cant-i-call-read-twice-on-an-open-file)

What you can do is use `communicate` and manually pass in the stdout data ( reads once, pass into both):

```py
out, err = p2.communicate() # out is None, since you don't 

p2_output = ''.join(list(out))

p3 = Popen([...], stdin=PIPE, ...)
p4 = Popen([...], stdin=PIPE, ...)

stdout_data3, err = p3.communicate(input=p2_output)
stdout_data4, err = p4.communicate(input=p2_output)
```

Also note, this might change the way polling needs to be done, in comparison to what you currently have.

related:

- [How do I write to a Python subprocess' stdin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8475290/how-do-i-write-to-a-python-subprocess-stdin)
- [How to read output from subprocess Popen correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29547454/how-to-read-output-from-subprocess-popen-correctly)

Comment: is using communicate more efficient than using the stdin=p2.stdout ?

Comment: @ShantanuShady i think in this case efficiency is less of a problem, and what is more of a concern is being able to customize the way the data is being passed to get the intended result, something that works, vs something that doesn't. To answer your question directly, I don't know off hand, however, i'd guess that since there is an extra step, or two, there might be a couple of microseconds difference. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil

Comment: thanks , had to decode it was coming as bytes
print('out is',  out.decode('utf8'))